# How to use C++ std functions in Cython?

Tags: c++11, cython

I would like to write a Cython function that involves strings, so of course I am inclined to use `libcpp.string`. But I could not figure out how to import std functions like `std::to_string()`.

What is the cleanest way to make std functions available to my Cython file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wrapper needs to be written. A full tutorial can be found on [docs.cython.org](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html). Some of the standard library has already been ported, but given the monumental effort needed to complete a task (and then do C++11), I highly doubt you'll see `std::to_string` any time soon.

Anyways, just write it yourself. `std::to_string` is just a wrapper over `std::sprintf` anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I will post my wrapper soon.